# As3 to YouTube Upload

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, youtube, webcam, youtube-api

I would like to know if it's possible to capture a users webcam in flash and directly upload it to YouTube without  a backend server setup. Or if there are any third party providers that support this service.

I see YouTube offers a live streaming API, but it seems it's only available for selected users.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, by using YouTube's [Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api). Basically you will interact with the API using XML and HTTP and then you can upload as well as any other functionality (create play lists, search, etc)